# How does Firebase implement its one-click rollback feature?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

[image]

All static files are hosting on CDN how Firebase make sure the most recent version of `index.html` file is fetched when the user made a network request?

Does this process involved with Nginx or something similar?

What's the process behind this **One-click** rollback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a version of you app/site, all the resources of your site/app are bundled up and sent to Firebase Hosting's servers. Firebase validates that the files are intact and then tells the CDN to flush its cache. The next time that an edge cache in the CDN receives a request for a file from your app/site, it requests that file from the Firebase Hosting origin servers.

The rollback of Firebase Hosting is quite similar to what happens when you deploy a new version of your site/app. Firebase Hosting takes the old bundle and essentially deploys it. From there the process is the same.

Comment: How does it find the right index.html file as the entry point?

Comment: The same way it found that file originally. The process of finding the default file to serve is unrelated to deployment or rollback. If you wonder how a web server does that, have a look at superstatic (the server that powers Firebase Hosting's delivery). One of the many example of its special handling for directory-to-index mapping:  https://github.com/firebase/superstatic/blob/85bcd83aa6936043fa8dcf898c5a9e60aa0e08ce/lib/middleware/files.js#L21